# How can I left align the labels in a customized description list

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumitem

I have this code:

```
\SetLabelAlign{rightbox}{\hss\llap{#1\quad}}
\setlist[description,1]{align=rightbox,labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=0pt}

    \section{Project 55d5396fed}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{19ex}}p{42em}}
    \begin{description}

    \item[student number] 55d5396fed



 \item[student name] We have already seen that a case of semigrammaticalness of a different sort is necessary to impose
an interpretation on irrelevant intervening contexts in selectional rules.

      \item[location] Of course, the fundamental error of regarding functional notions as categorial is to be regarded as
nondistinctness in the sense of distinctive feature theory.

       \end{description}
       \end{tabular}
```

The labels are right aligned. I want the labels to be left aligned. I mean the `items`.

Comment: Your example does not compile as-is (missing packages, document class etc.). Please add the minimal necessary code so that it does (this way other people can re-create your problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty way to achieve what you want. All I did was change your

```
\SetLabelAlign{rightbox}{\hss\llap{#1\quad}}
```

to

```
\SetLabelAlign{rightbox}{\hspace{-19ex}\rlap{#1\quad}}
```

Output before:

[image]

Output after:

[image]

The complete code becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

%\SetLabelAlign{rightbox}{\hss\llap{#1\quad}}
\SetLabelAlign{rightbox}{\hspace{-19ex}\rlap{#1\quad}}
\setlist[description,1]{align=rightbox,labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=0pt}

    \section{Project 55d5396fed}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{19ex}}p{42em}}
    \begin{description}

    \item[student number] 55d5396fed



 \item[student name] We have already seen that a case of semigrammaticalness of a different sort is necessary to impose
an interpretation on irrelevant intervening contexts in selectional rules.

      \item[location] Of course, the fundamental error of regarding functional notions as categorial is to be regarded as
nondistinctness in the sense of distinctive feature theory.

       \end{description}
       \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you guys are really great